# C program to copy one string into other string without using library functions

Tags: c, string

Below there is a program which is simply copying a string entered by the user into another string. This program is working fine for some of the inputs but showing anomaly for some of inputs of large strings. I'm unable to figure it out.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    printf("Enter a string : \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s1);
    for(i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        s2[i] = s1[i];
    }
    printf("\n the original string is %s\n", s1);
    printf("\n the string after copying is %s\n", s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Few input instances are : -

```
amitwebhero@AmitKali:~/c programs$ ./a.out
Enter a string : 
hi there..!!

 the original string is hi there..!!

 the string after copying is hi there..!!
```

Here the program is working fine, but considering the below case, it adds two extra garbage values at the end of the string.

```
amitwebhero@AmitKali:~/c programs$ ./a.out
Enter a string : 
my name is amit upadhyay 

 the original string is my name is amit upadhyay

 the string after copying is my name is amit upadhyay�.�4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings need to be null terminated. Ie they need a `'\0'` character at the end, so common string expressions can tell where the string ends. String functions like `strcpy` and `printf("%s...` look for this null termination in their operation. When you do this:

```
for(i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        s2[i] = s1[i];
```

You fail to copy the null terminator.  This means when you print the string, `printf` will go through the string until it finds the first `'\0'` character somewhere after the end of your string. This is why you see the extra characters, and in the case where the NULL is outside your strings allotted memory you will actually cause **undefined behaviour** by accessing unallocated space, which is very very bad.

You either need to null terminate your string by adding:

```
s2[i] = '\0'
```

After your for loop. Or even better, use a standard `c` function [`strcpy`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm).

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    printf("Enter a string : \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s1);
    for(i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        s2[i] = s1[i];
    s2[i] = 0; // null terminate the string
    printf("\n the original string is %s\n", s1);
    printf("\n the string after copying is %s\n", s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Or simply use `strcpy`.

Comment: Or, better, `strncpy`.

Comment: thank's , can you please tell why the resultant string was showing few garbage values? I mean there must be something wrong while printing the value with %s? As far as I know the printf function prints the string until the NULL character gets encountered. So from where is the NULL character is being encountered in the string? Or what may be the size of the string s2?

Comment: It's printing the garbage that was in memory before you used it until it finds a 0. There's no reason it should ever end besides pure chance -- and running outside the boundaries of virtual memory associated with your process.

Answer (score 2):

At least 2 issues

`s2` is not null character terminated.  suggest a `do` loop

```
i=0;
do {
  s2[i] = s1[i];
} while (s2[i++]);
```

No limit to input string length

```
char s1[100];
// scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s1);
scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", s1);
```

Note that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", s1);` and an input of `"\n"` will leave `s1` uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

you not copying terminating null character to s2, but you should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
int main( )
{
   char source[ ] = "this is a string" ;
   char target[20]= "" ;
   strcpy ( target, source ); //strcpy( ) function copies contents of one string into another string.
   printf ("\ntarget string = %s", target ) ;
   return 0;
}
```